# [webmaker-mediasync]: Retrieving data for all failed in mozila popcorn maker

Tags: node.js, popcornjs

I am stucked in mozzila popcorn maker. When I search for any thing of type you tube. 
My url is something like this :

```
http://localhost:8888/api/webmaker/search/all?page=1&q=mr%20bean
```

I am getting in response:

```
error: {code: "ECONNRESET", errno: "ECONNRESET", syscall: "read"}
code: "ECONNRESET"
errno: "ECONNRESET"
syscall: "read"
reason: "[webmaker-mediasync]: Retrieving data for all failed"
status: "failure"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of the wrong Youtube Sync API Key. I checked the code and working like a charm now.

Thanks everyone!